# How to get the variable and constraint of a cpsolver when using ortools

Tags: or-tools

As the topic, when I use ortools, I want to serialize cpsolver, CpSolverSolutionCallback and cpmodel to achieve multithread computing. However, I can't just serialize those objects directly and I think I need to only serialize their configuration and reset configuration in each thread, such as all the constraint and variables in the cpmodel and parameters in cpsolver. This is the question, how can I get all those values using ortools? Is there an api or something? I can't find it when searching on Google.

Comment: Which language?

Answer (score 1):

Every language implements a thin wrapper above a protocol buffer file.

This file is described [here](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/sat/cp_model.proto)

This model is accessible from each CpModel class.

Now you can distribute work using this proto directly. You will need to look at the CpSolver class to understand how the c++ Solve method is called.

See the python [solve method](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/b77bd3ac69b7f3bb02f55b7bab6cbb4bab3917f2/ortools/sat/python/cp_model.py#L1587).

The way to implement your request.

1. Create your model normally.
2. Extract the underlying protocol buffer model underneath and use it for parallelism/distribution.
3. Solve will returns a CpSolverResponse object. To get the value of a variable in the response, call `response.Value(var.Index())`, or store the index of the relevant variables and use it in the `Value()` method call.